# MYSQL The connection has timed out even I have defined in php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am running some reports and those reports takes more than 300 seconds to execute and finally display on browser.

I have already defined the max execution time in my code and also set the same in `php.ini`.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);
```

I am using MySQL Workbench to monitor the execution but on 300 sec browser shows

```
The connection has timed out. The server at localhost is taking too long to 
respond.
```

I just need to extend it to 400-500 sec and all of my reports will start working smoothly.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
```

This set the maximum execution time to unlimited. You could set this right before calling your report and set it back to a regular value, e.g 300 right after your report is done.

Comment: Worked for me nicely.
I have set it to ini_set('max_execution_time', 500);

Answer (score 0):

Your web server can have other Timeout configurations settings that may also interrupt PHP execution. `Apache has a Timeout Directive` which has default value to 300 seconds. Try changing the directive in your conf (httpd.conf for Apache) file.
[For more details , See Apache Timeout Directive doc.](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html)